# How to unit a sequence of dicts in Python

Tags: python, dictionary, python-3.3

I want to unit two dicts, but there are 10 dicts in a list, so how can I unit two by two without duplication?

I wrote something like this:

```
d_a1 = dict(list(dicts[0].items()) + list(dicts[1].items()))
d_b1 = dict(list(dicts[2].items()) + list(dicts[3].items()))
d_b2 = dict(list(dicts[4].items()) + list(dicts[5].items()))
d_b3 = dict(list(dicts[6].items()) + list(dicts[7].items()))
d_b4 = dict(list(dicts[8].items()) + list(dicts[9].items()))
```

Comment: Are there 9 or 10 (indices 0 to 9)? Your text contradicts your code.

Comment: @Hyperboreus, oh sorry about that. It's true that's 10, not 9. Sorry.

Comment: if there are duplicate keys, which dict will have precedence for key : value?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use:

```
for d1, d2 in zip(dicts[::2], dicts[1::2]):
    new_dict = dict(d1, **d2)
```

This pairs up the dictionaries and creates a new dictionary based on the two input dictionaries.

Further bringing this down to a loop with some iteration magic:

```
paired = [dict(d1, **d2) for d1, d2 in zip(*[iter(dicts)]*2)]
```

which produces a list of paired dictionaries.

Comment: aren't you pairing 0-1, 1-2, 2-3 ... instead of 0-1, 2-3 ... ?

Comment: Thanks very much Martijin!!! Clever ways to do it which I think I would not think about so ever!

Answer (score 2):

This creates a list of all paired dictionaries:

```
it = iter(dicts)
paired_dicts = [dict(x, **next(it)) for x in it]
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use:

```
import collections

newDicts = collections.deque((d1.update(d2) for d1,d2 in zip(*[iter(listOfDicts)]*2)), maxlen=0)
```

This should edit your dictionaries in-place. Thus, all the dictionaries in even numbered indices in your list of dictionaries would contain the union of itself and the dictionary in the very next index